# Runtime of DFS vs BFS

Tags: runtime, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

The running time of BFS is O(V+E) and that of DFS is Ө(V+E). As both DFS and BFS visit each vertex once and traverse all edges atmost twice, shouldn't the runtime of both be Ө(V+E)? Why are their running times different? In which scenarios are they different?

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia,

> "The time and space analysis of DFS differs according to its
>   application area. In theoretical computer science, DFS is typically
>   used to traverse an entire graph, and takes time Θ(|V| + |E|)"

The word *typically* leads to the case that this is just because of semantics. In the world of infinite memory, you could also *typically* use BFS for searching the whole graph, thus also having Ө(V+E).

Edit: Scenario in which they have different run time.

Suppose the Queue in which BFS is accessing is too large, that it have additional access time of O(log(K+E)). Then BFS's run-time would would be O(V + E + log(V+E)).

Whilst DFS will remain Θ(V+E) since the search is in low level cache.

Comment: yes, wikipedia also says that -"Thus, in this setting, the time and space bounds are the same as for breadth-first search and the choice of which of these two algorithms to use depends less on their complexity and more on the different properties of the vertex orderings the two algorithms produce." But I am unable to think possible scenarios where these 2 algorithms will lead to different runtimes. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Like said, they will run the same run time. But DFS is "typically" used to traversed the whole graph due to undesirable exponential memory growth of BFS. If you really want a separate scenario, you can add do the following (see edit).